# How to open a dialog on page load in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I am trying the 'new' HTML 5 dialogues and I want to open one when the page loads.

This is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dialogues</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <dialog>
      <p>This dialog should open right after page load</p>
    </dialog>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i put `open=""` to the `<dialog>`, it appears on the top of the page, not in the center.

And when I tried to put some JS,

```
<body onload="document.querySelector('dialog').showModal();"> ... </body>
```

it is not possible to close it - body reloads on dialog close, so it calls the `showModal()` again and it opens the dialog.

Is there any solution just with pure HTML and vanilla JS?